# Error when opening Texstudio from terminal: Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome-terminal, error-handling

I'm a new user of Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell XPS 13 plus laptop.
When I open Texstudio with the terminal, with the command

```
texstudio file.tex
```

everything works fine except that this message is displayed

```
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 146 (Unknown), sequence: 29288, resource id: 32, major code: 139 (Unknown), minor code: 20
```

From time to time, it also displays

```
"Object does not exist at path “/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/15”"
"Object does not exist at path “/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6”"
```

Is there some way to fix this issue? Is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the program otherwise works fine, then ignore these messages. If these messages bother you, you could make an alias that suppresses these messages:

```
alias texstudio='2>/dev/null texstudio'
```

To have this alias automatically set when you log in, add it to your `~/.bashrc` file.